# Going from ViewController -> DetailViewContoller ->ViewController and Navigation Item is empty?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am not sure what is happening. When i browse from ViewController to DetailViewController and with the back button to ViewController again, the navigation item "Title main" is empty or seems to be empty??

I also tried

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Title main"
```

[image]

A/ On main view controller I see the title item
[image]

B/ Navigation item title is empty on return??

[image: navigation item title is empty??]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the title in:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationItem.title = "Title main"
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: hmm already tried that one in both viewDidAppear as viewWillAppear. I added a screenshot of the layers and i notice the title isn't shown, is this correct?

Comment: No thats not correct. There should be a UINavigationItemView and a UILabel on top of it. How are you returning to the view controller?  Are you using navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated ?

Comment: No i am not using navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated. How can i check if i have done the Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller, maybe i have skip this??

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard at 50% zoom

Comment: Okay, I think I know the reason. Did you drag those nav bars onto the view controllers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100525/discussion-between-brl214-and-alex).